# Find specified expressions in string

Tags: java, android, regex, algorithm

I'm searching for a solution to find three sub-strings in a string.

My string looks like:

> John Smith tel. 555222333 mail. john@gmail.com

I want to get the phone number, email and name from this string. To find the email and phone number is trivial, but I don't know how to get name and surname.

edit.
Order of words in this string will not always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Word before tel. could be regarded as surname and everything before that as name.
Something like:

```
String names = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf("tel."));
String name = names.subString(0, names.indexOf(" "));
String surname = names.subString(names.indexOf(" "), names.size()-1);
```

Comment: I forgot to say that order of words will not always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Input String can be split around tel. and mail. eg:

```
String("John Smith tel. 555222333 mail. john@gmail.com").split("mail\\.\\B");
```

Here, \B makes sure that the String will not be split at mail.com. Then try below regex to get name:

```
[[[A-Za-z]+][\\s+]]+
```

This will search for the presence of at least one or more (+) name parts.
Here, a name part (i.e first, last or middle name) may start with and contain uppercase or lowercase characters. Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Retrieve telephone number. Remove it and string 'tel.' from the original string.

2. Retrieve email. Remove it and string 'mail.' from the original string.

3. Trim the remaining and you get the name.
```

This is the solution. But for the consistency of the style, it's better to put a string 'name.' before the name. Like this

```
"name. John Smith tel. 555222333 mail. john@gmail.com"
```